# How do I auto submit a dropdown when a value is selected other than the first value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Current Code:

```
<select name='PreviousReceiver' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
     <option value='0'>Contact List</option>
     <option value='1'>blah</option>
     <option value='2'>blah2</option>
     <option value='3'>blah3</option>
</select>
```

So I have this dropdown box that auto submits when the user clicks it. It works fine the way it is, but I dont want it to submit if the user has the first value selected(see above).

In other words, if the user clicks contact list, then I don't want it to submit the form.

I tried this:

```
 onchange="if(this.value != '0') this.form.submit()"
```

but that just made it never activate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QbJsS/1/ it seems to be working

Comment: If you are using jQuery then I believe it is `.val` and not `.value`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try without quotes and check.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/Ldet4/)

```
<form method="post">
    <select name='PreviousReceiver' onchange='if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }'>
         <option value='0'>Contact List</option>
         <option value='1'>blah</option>
         <option value='2'>blah2</option>
         <option value='3'>blah3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to call a function on change (use jquery):

```
<select name='PreviousReceiver' onchange='DoSubmit(this);'>
 <option value='0'>Contact List</option>
 <option value='1'>blah</option>
 <option value='2'>blah2</option>
 <option value='3'>blah3</option>
 </select>
```

Here goes your javascript function:

```
function DoSubmit(sel)
{
     if(sel.val()!='0') this.form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe you would like something like this?  This also disables the selection of the first item

```
<select name='PreviousReceiver' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
  <option selected disabled>Contact List</option>
  <option value='1'>blah</option>
  <option value='2'>blah2</option>
  <option value='3'>blah3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is the same answer as mentioned above,You need to make it more clear or little different.

Answer (score -2):

you have to write javascript keyword

SEE [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/H2QAx/)

```
 <form>
<select name='PreviousReceiver' onchange="javascript: if(this.value != '0') this.form.submit(); else alert('hello');" >
    <option value='0'>Contact List</option>
    <option value='1'>blah</option>
    <option value='2' selected>blah2</option>
    <option value='3'>blah3</option>
</select>
 </form>
```