# Auto submit a dropdown when a value is selected other than the first value?

Tags: reactjs

Current Code

**This is my Event Handler**

```
handleChangeStatus(event) {
    this.setState({
      addApp: {
        applicationStatus: event.target.value
      }
    });
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(this.state.addApp.applicationStatus);
    this.RPTList(event.target.value);
  }
```

**This one is Located at index**

```
<ApplicationStatusSelect value={this.state.addApp.applicationStatus} onChange={this.handleChangeStatus} appStatus={this.state.status} handle={this.state.handleShow}/>
```

**This one is my Component**

```
<Input id="applicationStatus" type="select" onChange={handle} name="applicationStatus" value={value}>
        <option value="">Status</option>
        {appStatus.map(appStatus =>
          <option key={appStatus.id} value={appStatus.id}>{appStatus.name}</option>
        )}
</Input>
```

It's a similar question from this link [How do I auto submit a dropdown when a value is selected other than the first value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086737/how-do-i-auto-submit-a-dropdown-when-a-value-is-selected-other-than-the-first-va)

but everything is in ReactJS

I tried Reacthooks and still having a hard time.

Comment: Just write submit code in onchange handler for select dropdown.. Rest everything is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Form should be like this

```
<ApplicationStatusSelect value={this.state.addApp.applicationStatus} handle={this.handleChangeStatus} appStatus={this.state.status}/>
```

OnChange on your Form is unnecessary, I'm guessing your whole component where like this.

```
const ApplicationStatusSelect = ({ appStatus, handle, value }) => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Input id="applicationStatus" type="select" onChange={handle} name="applicationStatus" value={value}>
        <option value="">Status</option>
        {appStatus.map(appStatus =>
          <option key={appStatus.id} value={appStatus.id}>{appStatus.name}</option>
        )}
      </Input>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ApplicationStatusSelect;
```

if it's still not working lemme know.

Comment: it works! I don't even need to use submit. I think the title will be misleading to the answer you present, but it works just fine for me.